# Twilio Website receive SMS form

Tags: twilio

How do produced a form Twilio SMS inbound  Displayed on website

Should look something look something like this

From             SMS Message                        Added
+1888xxxxx       hello                              1 minutes ago

Comment: Please be more precise on what the community can helps you.

Comment: Please show some of your attempts and ask questions about problem you ran into, this way people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Why don't you check out our quickstart guide on [receiving SMS messages with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey). It has an example PHP application and walks you through how to set it up to receive SMS messages.

Let me know if this helps or if you have other questions.

Comment: My English is not good, I do not understand
All I ask for help.

Comment: Sorry, I only speak English myself. We don't currently have tutorials in other languages either. Have you tried searching for a tutorial in your language elsewhere online?

Comment: I just started trying to learn to produce their own simple website. So, I hope someone can help me I talk to you use translation software

Comment: Dear foreign friends, you can give me a php script it?

Comment: There is a script and some details on this page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey I recommend you try to follow it as best as you can.

Comment: <?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Message>Hello, Mobile Monkey</Message>
</Response>                                                                                              I tried this script
I just received a reply message "Hello, Mobile Monkey"
Not display any information on my site

Comment: Did you connect that up with the Twilio number, like the tutorial suggests?

Comment: m0o0m.me/sms/sms.php连接脚本 This is my website

Comment: // this line loads the library 
require('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 
 
$account_sid = ''; 
$auth_token = ''; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 
 
$messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(   
)); 
 
foreach ($messages as $message) { 
 echo $message->body; 
}                                                                                                           How do I save a page should I change